# How to save excel file locally using angular2+electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, electron

```
getData(){
 return this.http.post(url,description,{responseType: 'blob' as 'json'})
      .subscribe(
        response =>{
          this.saveFile(response)
      },
           err => {
              console.log(err.error);

          }
       )
     }
}

saveFile(Data){
 var filename = dialog.showSaveDialog({ 
        defaultPath : "my_filename",
        filters: [{
         name: 'Microsoft Excel Worksheet',
         extensions: ['xlsx',]}]}
        ).then(result => {
          filename = result.filePath;
         if(filename === undefined) {
            alert('the user clicked the btn but didn\'t created a file');
            return;
        }
    fs.writeFileSync(filename,Data,'Binary',{encoding:"binary"},(err) => {
            if (err) {
              alert('an error ocurred with file creation ' + err.message);
              return
            }
               alert('WE CREATED YOUR FILE SUCCESFULLY');
          })
               alert('we End');
        }).catch(err => {
                alert(err)
        });
}
```

I am saving excel file into local system,but fs.writeFile saving Data is an empty and corrupted.
  I know that getting response from web api is Binary response.
  Please help!

Comment: Is your data inside the "Data" is correct? Could you please share the data that you are trying to write in the file.

Comment: Blob {size: 7121, type: "text/html"}
size: 7121
type: "text/html"
__proto__: Blob                                                                                                         //In log Iam getting this type of response from backend service

Comment: Please try writeFileSync instead of writeFile. Hope this helps.

Comment: try using writeFileSync also getting same issue.whatever getting response from backend service is Binary format.So I need to make any conversion in my client side code.

Comment: please provide your `filename` and `Data`

Comment: I am not creating Data.The thing is whatever getting response from backend service I am trying to save as  xlsx format and file saving is working fine.But after saving the file If I try to open its giving this type of issue https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMBt9.png

Comment: Blob {size: 7121, type: "text/html"}  //back end response